# How to go about combining dropdowns / filter queries?

Tags: loop, query, search

I'm coming up short with my googling here. (As 'filter' in wordpress always turns up more content related info).

Anyway, my situation is this: I have `Categories`, `Tags`, `Authors` and `Archive` dropdowns on my blog page (using the built in wordpress dropdown functionality (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories, for example).

I want to be able to combine these filters; such that if you choose a category `Hats`, and then when you have your list of results if you choose `Blue` from the dropdown you would get anything that matched both `Blue` and `Hats`. (Or if you choose a month, you'd get the posts *that* matched `Blue` and `Hat` from your chosen month.)

I know there has to be a way to do this. But I'm coming up short even figuring out where to start. (I'm certain there was a plugin that did this that I wanted to look at, but I can't even find that.)

So... If anyone has any ideas about how to start this that would be amazing. Or even just an example plugin I can look at to glean some info (I really want to code this myself so I understand *what* is going on).

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is "faceted search", it's popular feature to be required, should be plenty info on it around.

Answer (score 1):

To get you started: you can make a custom form (I never worked with wp_dropdown_categories). When the form is submitted, it gets the input variables and uses them in the query.

The form could be something like:

```
<form action="http://example.com/resultspage" method="post">
<select name="categories">
   <option value="categoryname1"></option>
   <option value="categoryname2"></option>
   <option value="categoryname3"></option>
</select>
<select name="tags">
   <option value="tagname1"></option>
   <option value="tagname2"></option>
   <option value="tagname3"></option>
</select>
<select name="authors">
   <option value="authorname1"></option>
   <option value="authorname2"></option>
   <option value="authorname3"></option>
</select>
<select name="archives">
   <option value="archivesname1"></option>
   <option value="archivesname2"></option>
   <option value="archivesname3"></option>
</select>
</form>
```

And then on the resultspage

```
$category = $_POST['categories'];
$tag = $_POST['tags'];
$author = $_POST['authors'];
$archive = $_POST['archives'];

$args = array(
    'category' => $category,
    'tag' => $tag,
    'author' => $author,
    'posts_per_page' => -1 // Number of posts per page, -1 is show all 
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

A few notes. First, this is not tested. Second, check the [codex on WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) how to use these (and other) arguments and what kind of input they need. For instance, you can use `'tag'` and input the tag slug, but you can also use `'tag_id'` and use the tag ID as input. Then you would change the option value of the tags select field. Third: I don't know what you would like to do with the archives. Would you like to display posts from a certain month? This can be achieved with a meta_query (you can find documentation in the WP codex).

Is this a good start? Let me know if it worked out.